# StreamColorFunction ignored when setting to the RGB color

Tags: plotting, color

Recently I needed to color streamlines with exact color (e.g. RGBColor[0.1,0.478,0.5]). The help (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamColorFunction.html) suggests, that this can be achieved by setting StreamColorFunction to some value ("The function specified by StreamColorFunction must return color directives such as RGBColor and Hue or named colors such as Red and Blue."), however in the examples the only option used is "hue", which produces rather fancy colored streams for me (?). I'd like to have all streams e.g. Red, or Yellow, but all of the following codes:

```
StreamPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, StreamColorFunction -> Yellow]

StreamPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, StreamColorFunction -> Red]

StreamPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, StreamColorFunction -> RGBColor[0,0,0]]
```

produces default blue streamlines, instead of yellow, red or black (there is a slight possibility that I'm color blinded since today, but I doubt it :)). Why is the StreamColorFunction behaving this way? Is there a possibility to color streams with any color I like?
Any help'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a **function** ...you need to specify one:

```
StreamPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  StreamColorFunction -> (Yellow &)]

StreamPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  StreamColorFunction -> (Red &)]

StreamPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  StreamColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0, 0, 0] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sure, it works, thanks, but why?

Comment: @user16320 Because ... the option needs a function as input, not a color

Comment: @user16320 Read the "Details" section right on the help

Comment: ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use `StreamStyle`:

```
Grid[{StreamPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
     StreamColorFunction -> None, StreamStyle -> #] & /@ {Red, Green, Blue}}]
```

[image]

Comment: When running this code in v14, the specified colors are not displayed in the output.

Comment: Thanks for spotting. We now have to add `StreamColorFunction -> None` (see updated answer)